# How to update controls of FormArray

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My form group code is as

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({            
            branch_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
            branch_timing: this._fb.array([
                this.initBranchTiming(),
            ])                                
        });

initBranchTiming() {       
        return this._fb.group({
            day: ['', []],
            open_from: ['00:00:00', []],
            open_till: ['00:00:00', []]           
        });
  }
```

branch_name is updated by this code

```
(<FormControl>this.myForm.controls['branch_name']).updateValue(this.branch_detail.branch_name);
```

Now i have to update the 'day' field of form array. what to do to update the 'day' field of form array branch_timing ?

Answer (score 23):

AFAIK putting a `FormGroup` inside of a `FormArray` strips the 'FormControls' of their names and makes it just a list, like a normal array.

In order to update the `FormControls` individually, you update the value of each `AbstractControl` from the `FormGroup` by using the index:

```
let index = 0; // or 1 or 2
(<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['branch_timing']).at(index).patchValue('example');
```

Or you can update the entire `FormArray` by calling `setValue` or `patchValue`:

```
(<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['branch_timing']).setValue(['example', 'example1', 'example2']);
```

`setValue` requires an array that matches the entire structure or the `FormArray`, while `patchValue` can take a super-set or sub-set of the array. ([FormArray-class on Angular2's website](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html))

Comment: @Frederico P Best advice found online for adding to a formArray! Still, I needed this to get it working: `(<FormArray>this.formName.get('FormArrayName')).push(new FormControl('SOME VALUE'));`

Comment: in case you want to replace the day, for instance, I did it like this: (<FormArray>this.myForm.controls['branch_timing']).at(index).get("day").setValue("222");

Comment: FormArray must have the same number of items in the array you want to update it with or else you get nasty errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is tested and works on Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 with @angular/forms 0.2.0:

```
(<FormControl>this.myForm.controls.branch_timing.controls[0].controls.day)
  .updateValue('new value');
```

In the release version, Angular 2.0.0 with @angular/forms 2.0.0, the syntax has been simplified:

```
this.myForm.value.branch_name = this.branch_detail.branch_name;
```

and

```
this.myForm.value.branch_timing[0].day = 'New Value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by creating a new FormControl :

```
this.form.setControl('items',  new FormControl(arrayItemsValue));
```

Or by removing all items before updating them :

```
const items = (<FormArray>this.form.get('items'));
 for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
     items.removeAt(i);
 }
 this.form.get('items').setValue(arrayItemsValue);
```

Answer (score -5):

Try it, hope it will work for you:

```js
 this.myForm.controls.splice(0);
```

Comment: Sorry, it's mistake

Comment: you should be able to delete it. Search for "delete" link under your answer