# Angular 2 remove or add data to form.value object

Tags: forms, angular, form-submit

I need to remove "toys" from **form.value** object before submit, and add new data to 'price'. But controls must be declared.

**form.value object**

```
{
  "red": 1,
  "green": 3,
  "black": "120",
  "blue": 3,
  "toys": [
    {
      "bear": 0,
      "soldier": 0,
      "car": 0
    }
  ],
  "price": [
    {
      "default": 123,
      "pre": 3,
      "after": 2
    },
    {
      "default": 3,
      "pre": 0,
      "after": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**ts**

```
 initForm() {
        this.form = this._fb.group({
        red: 0,
        green: 0,
        black: '',
        blue: 0,
        toys: this._fb.array([this.inittoys()]),
        price: this._fb.array([this.initprice()]),

   });
```

**html**

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="black">Max travel time</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="black" formControlName="black">
       <option *ngFor="let t of colors; let i=index" [ngValue]="i">{{t}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: For clearing an array check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852183/angular-2-remove-all-items-from-a-formarray .
For patch an array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229398/how-to-update-controls-of-formarray
Try to google first next time ;)

Comment: Shame on me. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the values in the function before you send the form like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="yourForm" (ngSubmit)="yourSendFunction(yourForm.value)">
```

....

in the component:

```
yourSendFunction(values) {

  delete values.toys;

  values.price.push({
             // Here anything you wants to addd
              })

  // Next send the values
```

}